# Jquery slideshow works local but not online

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

Wondering if anyone can help me. I have a site (for the moment ) hosted at http://www.jn-design.co.uk/REdesign

The image within the computer under "portfolio" is meant to be a slideshow. This works completely fine locally.

When it is hosted online the slideshow does not work at all. I have checked all the file references and disabled the other jquery function (scroll function - 1.5.1) and it still does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Off topic: contact page - "you're" not "your".

Comment: Thanks! Stupid error! This is a work in progress remember ha!

Comment: First look - DOCTYPE declaration should always be on very first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither your jquery-1.7.1-min.js nor jquery-slider.js is loaded
[image]

you can use firebug for firefox or chrome inbuilt web developer tool to debug such error.

Answer (score 1):

Line 60. The link to your /themes/3/jquery-slider.js is 404ing. The location is obviously wrong, and this is why your slideshow is broken.

Comment: I have changed the slideshow and working on something else. Sorry!

The failed jquery calls were not the reason for the problem though! It has puzzled me , I have moved onto a different solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.jn-design.co.uk/REdesign/themes/3/jquery-1.7.1.min.js`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.jn-design.co.uk/REdesign/themes/3/jquery-slider.js`

The error console reports these errors fix them!